# Turn off backup for an "Azure database for MySql server" resource

Tags: azure, azure-mysql-database

I have an "Azure database for MySql server" resource.
The database size is 2.5GB.
The backup size is 143GB.
This has added 10€ to my last invoice, but i'm mostly concerned about how large can it grow in the future, when the application will go from TEST to LIVE.
The backup is already set to the minimum retention time (7 days).
I did not found any option to turn the backup off (as it doesn't add much value to my application, for most of the tables it's pointless to have a backup), or anything that could reduce its size.
The only thing i can think of is to reduce the WRITE operations, but meh, is this really what i'm supposed to do for a backup size issue?

For those wondering, backups are taken every few minutes and it's possible to restore the situation at any moment in the the past configured time span (from 7 to 30 days, 7 days in my case), so i guess that what is making the database grow are WRITE(insert,update,delete) operations.

Comment: Couldn't find any option in azure portal and updating backup retention-period other than 7-35 did not work. Please update if you find any workaround :)